# Is RaspberryPi OpenCV fast enough to run eye blink recognition?

Tags: performance, opencv

I would like to create application that can recognise eye blink recognition on RaspberryPi with Raspberry Pi Noir camera.

Eye blinks are fast, so I will have to process many frames per second.

Is RaspberryPi fast enough to do such things?

Anyone tried such things?

Edit / more information:

I don't know yet how high resolution I need to recognise eye blink. I think VGA should be enough.

I need realtime processing (from camera).

Comment: that depends on quite a few things.
Is the data a live stream from a camera? or a pre-recorded video?
What is the resolution of the video stream?

Comment: @Timothy Groote we r using 5 mp pi camera to detect the blinks.is it possible?

Comment: you will definitely want to request a video stream with a resolution lower than 5MP if you intend to do processing of a live stream on a RPI.